# Unable to update the `$scope` index value from DOM click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my directive, i have custom templates and replacing with existing one. when the custom templates click, i need to update the `$scope.index` to update.

but it's not working. but when i console the property it all works. what is the correct way to do this?

here is my custom directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('main', function ($scope) {

  $scope.values = [{"name":"one", "num" : 1}, {"name":"two", "num" : 2}, {"name":"three", "num" : 3}]

  $scope.index = 0;

  $scope.update = function (num) {
    $scope.index = num;
  }

});

myApp.directive("newArray", function ($compile) {

  return {

    scope : {
      value : "=",
      index : "=",
      update:"&"
    },

    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var getTemplate = function (val, index) {

        switch(index) {

          case 0 :
            return $('<div />', {
              class:'red',
               html : "<h1>testing</h1>",
              click : function () {
                console.log(scope.value.num); //works
                scope.update(scope.value.num); //not wroking
              }
            });
            break;

            case 1 :
            return $('<div />', {
              class:'blue',
              html : "<h1>testing</h1>",
              click : function () {
                scope.update(scope.value.num);
              }
            });
            break;

            case 2 :
            return $('<div />', {
              class:'green',
              html : "<h1>testing</h1>",
              click : function () {
                scope.update(scope.value.num);
              }
            });
            break;

        }

      }

      element.html(getTemplate(scope.value, scope.index));
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      element.replaceWith(element.contents());

    }

  }

})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JOp3ffzQQ2HITImoYrAW?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the html change the line

```
<new-array index='$index' update="update" value='value' ng-repeat="value in values">{{value.name}}</new-array>
```

to

```
<new-array index='$index' update="update($index)" value='value' ng-repeat="value in values">{{value.name}}</new-array>
```

In the js change:

```
scope.update(scope.value.num);
```

to

```
scope.update({num: scope.value.num});
```

and finally change:

```
$scope.update = function (num) {
    $scope.index = num;
  }
```

to

```
 $scope.update = function (num) {
    $scope.index = num;
    $scope.$apply();
  }
```

See [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8qZV2dw3NSriaUg2MzMQ?p=preview)

Comment: As a first click, I am getting error... what is wrong in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "as a first click, I am getting error"? Did you try the plunker. It's working fine in my browser. I have modified your code for the second and third item to work.

Comment: In my actual project, I am not getting result. when click on the dive i am console the update function, it return like `$get.d.(anonymous function)()', but not calling the function.. any idea to fix this

Comment: You'd have to provide some sample code for me to analyze. Did you call $scope.$apply() at the right place? It is necessary as the click event from jquery is outside of the angularjs digest cycle.

Comment: Here is my `controller and `directive` with `html` file. can you have a look in this? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/homeController.zip

Comment: In controller file search `//app Gallery ` to fine the `update` function. `dirHome.js` file search `allAppsGallery` to go to function, and in html file find `<all-apps-gallery` directive.

Comment: At first glance I can see that the html is not correct. The line update="update" is missing the parameter, like this:   update="update(app)"

Comment: And I think the line in the directive  scope.update({newApp:app}); should be:    scope.update({app:app});

Comment: sure let me try. and get back to you

Comment: as a information, on click, by `ng-show` i am running this directive. is that ok?

Comment: Is the update function being called? Try put a console.log(app) in the update statement.

Comment: No that's not called at all.. that's what the issue. already i consoling your suggestion. please check in my controller file

Comment: Try putting a console.log(scope.update) in the click function to see if the function is visible. The result should be something like this: destination.(anonymous function)(locals)

Comment: I try like this 'html : '<h2 ng-click="update()">'+app.completion+'%</h2><span>'+app.name+'</span>',` and I got the error as `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply`

Comment: yes, i consoled as `function()  $get.d.(anonymous function)()` - like so. but there is no `destination` and `(locals)`

Comment: The error $rootScope:inprog means that the angularjs digest cycle is already in progress. Instead of $scope.$apply() wrap the alert in the update function with $timeout. This should prevent the error firing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81713/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-zszep).